# How do I translate substrings in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to make a translator that translates R U R' U' into r^ u< rv u>. This is very difficult because R' has R in it. So when I try to use this, it spits a result back to me like

```
put in your algorithm: R U R' U'
r^ u< r^' u<'
```

Not a very human way of doing it. I think this is because R is a substring of R', but this is what I have been told. I am using this translation thingy from a package called luastring. The dev of luastring won't help me, and this question is too advanced for everyone on the discord server. This is what I have tried so far.

```lua
io.write("put in your algorithm: ")
local alg = io.read()

function split(str, pat)
    local t = {}
    local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
    local last_end = 1
    local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
    while s do
        if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then table.insert(t, cap) end
        last_end = e + 1
        s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
    end
    if last_end <= #str then
        cap = str:sub(last_end)
         table.insert(t, cap)
    end
    return t
end

-- table stuff so we can see
local moves = {"R", "U", "L", "F", "D", "B", "M", "E", "S", "R'", "U'", "L'", "F'", "D'", "B'", "M'", "E'", "S'"}
local neomoves = {"r^", "u<", "lv", "f>", "d>", "b<", "mv", "e>", "s>", "rv", "u>", "l^", "f<", "d<", "b>", "m^", "e<", "s<"}
local string = require("luastring")

local translation_table = {
    ["R'"] = "rv", ["U'"] = "u<", ["L'"] = "lv", ["F'"] = "f>", ["D'"] = "d>", ["B'"] = "b<", ["M'"] = "mv", ["E'"] = "e>", ["S'"] = "s>", ["R"] = "r^", ["U"] = "u<", ["L"] = "lv", ["F"] = "f>", ["D"] = "d>", ["B"] = "b<", ["M"] = "mv", ["E"] = "e>", ["S"] = "s>"
}

-- translate the moves to neomoves
local translated = string.translate(alg, translation_table)
print(translated)
```

What on earth do I have to do to let Lua know what it is supposed to do?

Comment: `local translated = alg:gsub("%a'?", translation_table)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your translated string is lower case and the source string is upper case you can simply translate `R'` befor you translate `R`.

You only need to split your `translation_table` into two.

Also you can simply use Lua's standard string.gsub for this. I don't see why you would use luastring here.

Simplified example:

```
local str = "R' R R' R'"
local t_a = {["R'"] = "rv"}
local t_b = {["R"] = "r^"}
print((str:gsub("%S+", t_a):gsub("%S+", t_b)))
```